# python submodule can't find import

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, filesystems

So I have a module called gann which itself has a number of modules, the problem is that if I run gannController.py directly it fails.

I have the following file structure(some files omitted):

```
----convert
    __init__.py
    convert.py
    ----AI
        __init__.py
        ----gann
            gannController.py
            ----model
                __init__.py 
                modelController.py 
    ----util
```

now I want to use the gannController.py in the convert.py file.

```
from AI.gann import gannController
```

in convert.py does import gannController, however it crashes on the first line which is

```
from model import modelController
```

which does work if I run gannController.py directly. As it gives the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named model
```

So I guess that it's because a submodule uses a submodule of it's own that I cannot run this. Anybody know how to fix this? It's worth noting that I would prefer not to pollute my convert namespace with all of the stuff in model and that I have omitted a few other modules that have the same situation (inside util)

Comment: I'm of course open to question/suggestions. And thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @GProst ModuleNotFoundError: No module named model

Comment: `from model import modelController` This line is in which file?

Comment: @EduardoBarrancos It is in `gannController.py` according to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your import to be relative:

```py
from .model import modelController
```